# Firebase security for root variable

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase security something like this

```
{
 "rules":{
   "item":{
     "$items":{
       ".write": "root.child('user').child('is').val() === true"
     }
   },
   "user":{
     "$is": "....."
   }
 }
}
```

But root file is only getting "item" section not main "rules" section How can I solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: What user are you trying to validate? If it's the currently authenticated user, you'll want to use `root.child('user').child(auth.uid).val() === true`

Comment: currently this is just demo my security rule is completely different The thing i want to understand here `root` variable

Comment: The `root` variable points to the root of your Firebase data. The `rules` node in the security rules has no meaning and is just needed to make sure the rules are valid JSON.

Comment: is my code above correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do that. The root variable is the root of your dataset, not the rules. As far as I know, there’s no methods to traverse the rule set - only the data.